# How does one move the cursor to the next line without entering in the command prompt?

Tags: c, string, terminal

I have just started to learn the C language and am having trouble figuring out how to input strings into a terminal onto different lines, and if this feature will have a significant impact on my code. My program is supposed to read strings inputted from the command prompt and display the 5 most frequently used words. zzzzz is the terminator string

```
> i must not fear 
> fear is the mind killer 
> fear is the little death that brings total obliteration 
> i will face my fear 
> i will permit it to pass over me 
> and through me and when it has gone past i will turn the inner eye to see its path 
> where the fear has gone there will be nothing only
> i will remain 
> zzzzz 
>
> Count Word
> ===== ==== 
> 5     fear 
> 5     i 
> 5     will 
> 4     the 
> 2     and
```

How does one separate lines of input while in the terminal like the above example? And if this feature is possible, will it have an effect when using functions like  fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *"inputted from the command prompt"* Typically, your program takes control of the terminal when running, so the command prompt is suspended until your program finishes.

Comment: Mostly, you just use `fgets()` and don't worry about it all.  If you're using `fgets()` sensibly (`char buffer[4096]; while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0) { … }` — and yes, I do mean 4 KiB for the line buffer; that's peanuts except on embedded systems, and if you've got a keyboard, you aren't in that embedded of a system — then you'll read whole lines, and can process each one in turn.